# How to request a professor who has moved colleges to acknowledge project work?

Tags: professorship, research-undergraduate, communication, projects

At the end of last semester , I had taken up some research work under a professor of a different department.

Now , I had been updating him with my progress on a weekly basis until my final exams arrived , due to which I was forced to put a hold on the project work. 
After my final exams got over, I came to know that the professor has moved colleges.

So, I was thinking of mailing him the progress I have made on the project. Now , the issue is there has been almost a month since he moved colleges but I have anyway been constantly working on the project.

If I manage to get him to acknowledge my work and  get a recommendation from him, it would be pretty neat. So how do I go about framing the email?

Comment: Can you provide a draft of your email so that we can comment? Can you also search for similar questions?

Comment: @user2768 Draft of which email? I had been updating him with the progress in person.

Comment: You want to know how to "go about framing the email," write the email and show us, then we can guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he is personally available (different College, same place) then go see him with an update as usual. If not, then email him with the update as an attachment.

But, in either case, also ask him if he is willing to keep advising you on a less formal basis and tell him that you are continuing work and value his feedback. It may be possible for him to continue or not. If not, ask him if he will write you a letter of recommendation then or later.

Actually, it is pretty simple. "Just ask" is usually the right move in these situations. You don't learn unless you ask.

Welcome to Academia.